# Special character not getting displayed in UI

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, special-characters

I have the following effect that is to be added to one of my buttons:

```
.custom-button:after {
    content: "➜";
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 14px;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

The effects except the the special character are successfully getting applied to my button.

Tried few sites to check that I should try using `\279C` or `&#8594;` and to have `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` defined in my page. Done everything. Nothing seems to work.

Any help on guiding would mean a lot.

**UPDATE**:

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wya8vx9e/) which is the same code I have used in my project.

Comment: I have a text for the button defined in html. That is getting displayed even after this effect. Hope opaque should not be a problem.

Comment: Yes, my solution was simplified, but what you need to do is use your original CSS; onlym the HTML for the button should change. Anyway, next time you have a problem, remember to post all the code necessary to reproduce the problem. The CSS here at first was not enough, so all you could get was guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When boiled down to the absolute minimum required to demonstrate the problem, your code looks like this:

```css
.custom-button::after {content:'➜';}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="custom-button" value="Sign in"/>
```

but `<input>` elements don't have content, so they don't have any `::before` or `::after` content either.

The solution is to turn the button into a `<button>`, which does have content.

```css
.custom-button::after {content:'➜';}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="custom-button">Sign in</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find my codepen solution here: https://codepen.io/GarrettManley/pen/GYYoyG

As Mr Lister stated, The solution is to turn the button into a `<button>`

Here are my modifications to your code from jsfiddle.

```
<button type="submit" style="border-radius:20px; width:150px; margin-top:25px;" class="btn btn-primary custom-button" onclick="sessionStorage.setItem('fileName','');">Sign In</button>
```

As far as CSS goes, here is my interpretation of what I think you were going for.  I only included the bare minimum here because I wasn't entirely sure what the expected result was.

```
.custom-button:hover {
  background-color: #219025 !important;
  border-color: #219025 !important;
}

.custom-button:hover::after {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.custom-button::after {
  content: '\2192';
  display: none;
}
```